# Qual é a origem da palavra «motumbada»?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gíria

Motumbada é quando o operador da bolsa sofre um grande prejuízo. Muito obrigado.

https://forex-brazil.com/showthread.php?9473-G%C3%ADrias-do-mercado-financeiro

Comment: Pergunta p'ra eles. Acho que ninguém aqui vai saber. A origem deve ser africana: motumbá.

Comment: Алексей Митрошин, será que não estás confundindo com "mó tombada" ou "mó tumbada"?

Comment: Não. Em todas as fontes esta palavra se escreve assim. Por exemplo: «Continuando nos termos relacionados ao fracasso, nabo e, também, motumbada são expressões utilizadas para se referir a um grande prejuízo.»
https://www.dicionarios-online.com/as-expressoes-mais-famosas-no-mundo-das-financas-melhor-site-de-apostas/

Comment: Não estou convencido que "motumbada" seja uma palavra e não uma frase. Acho que as pessoas se confundiram e escreveram "motumbada" em vez de "mó tombada" ou algo do gênero.

Comment: Uma pedra de moinho a que tombou?

Comment: Olá, já há muito tempo que negoceio forex, esta é a primeira vez que vejo esta palavra

Comment: @АлексейМитрошин "uma pedra de moinho que tombou"? Não, isso seria em pt-PT. Em pt-BR, "mó" é uma abreviação de maior, como em pt-PT "pá" é abreviação de rapaz. Mó tombada, então, seria "maior tombada", "uma grande tombada". Tombada deve ser o significado de "queda" do verbo [tombar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/tombar) (cair), mas como não sou brasileiro não sei com certeza... abre uma nova pergunta se quiseres saber. :)

Comment: @ANeves, sim. Era nisso que estava pensando. A palavra *tombada* é uma queda que se percebe forte, como alguém caindo de uma escada ou uma criança caindo da prateleira. A palavra "mó" é normal para dar ênfase, ainda mais na fala. Assim, se uma criança cai, eu talvez diga «Jesus! Mó tombada, o menino!». Então, como geralmente quando invesamentos dão prejuízos seu gráfico mostra queda, talvez se diga «Mó tombada ontem, na PETR4...». De curiosidade, existem investimentos em que se primeiro compra e, então, vende, ganhando na queda.

Answer (score 2):

Sua origem aparentemente é "Motumbo", um [personagem fictício](https://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Bengalel%C3%AA_Motumbo) cômico com um pênis de proporções inverossímeis.

O Corpus do Português [revela](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/web-dial/) postagens de 2013, já inacessíveis, que deixam claro que "motumbar" é usado com o significado de "ter prejuízo (financeiro)", mais especificamente do vulgarismo "[foder-se](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/foder/) (financeiramente)":

> - A classe C que ` salvou' o Brasil da crise de 2008 está motumbada. Adeus viagem aérea.
> - amiga.. ainda bem que vc é mulher... uai pq? Vc será Motumbada. Que isso? é o Motumbo!!!

E o termo "Motumbo" tem ainda mais exemplos dessa época:

> - entre em essa pirâmide e receba grátis uma visita semanla do Motumbo
> - meros espucaladores / amadores que amargarão o MOTUMBO!
> - e quando a ação minguar... nhac! O motumbo aparece e enfia a mandioca e fica com tudo a preço de nada!

O personagem "Motumbo" a que essas postagens provavelmente se referem foi aparentemente popularizado no Brasil por um programa humorístico (talvez o [CQC](https://www.mundogump.com.br/as-licoes-que-chaves-nos-ensinou-e-que-nao-foram-aprendidas/) ou o [Pânico na TV](https://sodtv.wordpress.com/2009/07/27/nesta-semana-o-panico-e-300/)) nos anos 2000s — o [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=BR&q=motumbo) registra a palavra desde 2004 (início dos registros) e revela um pico de interesse em 2007. E se poderia especular que o nome "Motumbo" foi inspirado pela palavra [matumbo](https://www.dicio.com.br/matumbo/):

> Cova em que se planta, de estaca, a mandioca.

Embora, como apontado pelo Jacinto, a palavra já seja encontrada em inglês num [texto](https://avaruusmies.com/jokes/the-story-of-motumbo-and-mary.html) de 1999.

Essa gíria financeira não parece ser de uso amplo (em 2021), sendo apenas encontradas em sites pouco relevantes (e.g., [1](https://defendaseudinheiro.com.br/termos-do-mercado-financeiro), [2](https://chegadeperderdinheiro.com.br/glossario-de-termos-do-mercado-financeiro/), [3](https://www.operefuturos.com.br/noticias/as-curiosas-girias-do-mercado-financeiro/) e [4](https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/post/13539-os-principais-jargoes-da-publicidade-marketing-digital-mercado-financeiro-etc)), cujas datas de publicação sugerem ter sido cunhada em 2013 e pouco usada desde então.

Comment: Não acredito!  Eu tive tal versão também, mas pareceu um pouco indecorosa. Você fez o meu dia! Muito, muito obrigado!

Comment: Me discupe. Como posso citar a sua ideia?

Comment: @АлексейМитрошин Clicando no "Share" sob a resposta. Pode também (up)votar, se achou útil.

Comment: Não sei se conheces o [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=motumbo)? Mostra que o nome *Motumbo* já circula na net desde pelo menos 2004 (tem de ser anterior a 2013 para poder ser a origem de *motumbada*); e em vários países; clica no Brasil, para ver só lá. Vi no Google geral que já em 2003 circulava uma anedota acerca de um Motumbo muito dotado...

Comment: @Jacinto Note que escrevi: "criado [...] nos anos 2000s." O ano de 2013 é apenas o da mais antiga referência que encontro para o uso com o significado financeiro. Mas checar o Google Trends é mesmo uma boa ideia.

Comment: Eu abri o primeiro desses links, CQM, vi data de 2010, não vi imediatamente nada acerca do Motumbo, e fui ver se encontrava mais antigo :). A "história do Motumbo" circulou em várias línguas. Tens [uma em inglês](https://avaruusmies.com/jokes/the-story-of-motumbo-and-mary.html) com data de 1999.

Comment: Interessante, obrigado @Jacinto! Incluí suas referências na resposta. Me pergunto se, apesar da referência mais antiga (também procurei agora sem achar nada anterior a 1999) ser em inglês, se a origem seria brasileira...

Comment: Perguntas bem! Não será fácil achar coisas na net anteriores a 1999. Mas a histórias que eu vi em inglês e português são a mesma e passam-se em Londres com um senegalês e uma inglesa. Logo há uma boa probabilidade de a história brasileira ser uma tradução. Vi também títulos, sem ler a história, em espanhol, italiano e alemão.

Comment: Yeah, I said it was African, didn't I?